# What to do in order to create a continuous .txt files without replacing the already existing .txt files using bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to write a bash script to create multiple .txt files.

With the below code I created the files, but when I run the script again I get the same output instead of having more files with increasing number.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

for z in $(seq -w 1 10);
do
    [[ ! -f "${z}_name.txt" ]] && {touch "${z}_name.txt";}
done
```

Comment: seq -w 1, 10 doesn't look right. Even if it worked, it would generate the same numbers and hence the same files every time it is run any way.

Comment: If you need to generate different numbers based on which files are already present, you have to look at what's around and use that information to control the generated numbers.  That can easily get to be tricky — it depends on how hostile a setup you have.  Is anyone or anything else creating files in the directory? What should happen if there are files `01_name.txt` to `10_name.txt` and also `1001_name.txt`?  More tricky still; what if the largest number is in `998_name.txt`?

Comment: @RamanSailopal, What do you suggest I do, because I want a situation where I can keep creating different files each time the script is run?

Comment: Get the highest number from the files (if there are/is any files at all), a loop, test for files, and increment the number. Then again that's easier said than done...

Comment: And to spell out why `998_name.txt` gives problem, the largest number is 998, so you need to run `seq -w 999 1008` but that yields 0999, 1000, ... 1008, which doesn't match the previous 3-digit numbers.  You'll have to decide whether that matters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, from what I am trying to achieve, it does not matter

Comment: Undoubtedly, the easiest way is to make the user do the thinking — require them to pass the start and stop numbers as command-line arguments (`$1` and `$2`) and use `seq -w ${1:?} ${2:?}` to generate the numbers.  The `${1:?}` notation generates an error message if the variable `$1` is not set to a non-null value.   You probably want a system that doesn't require the user to do the thinking, though.  In that case, your script must do the equivalent thinking.

Comment: @Ossy, I'd strongly suggest deciding how many files you could ever need, and padding out your numbers to have that many digits (thus, starting with something like `000001_name.txt`). That way an ASCII sort will be able to be in numeric order, instead of needing to do a numeric sort (and shell globs, like `*.txt`, will also be in the right order by default).

Comment: @Ossy, ...otherwise, you get problems where `20` sorts as a lower number than `3`, because the default behavior just looks character-by-character.

Answer (score 1):

Based in part on work by [Raman Sailopal](https://.com/users/7840440/raman-sailopal) in a now-deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66693786/15168) (and on comments I made about that answer, as well as comments I made about the question), you could use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
touch $(seq -f '%.0f_name.txt' \
            $(printf '%s\n' [0-9]*_name.txt |
              awk 'BEGIN { max = 0 }
                         { val = $0 + 0; if (val > max) max = val; }
                   END   { print max + 1, max + 10 }'
             )
       )
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` command means that if there are no names that match the glob expression `[0-9]*_name.txt`, nothing will be generated in the arguments to the `printf` command.

The `touch` command is given a list of file names.  The `seq` command formats a range of numbers using zero decimal places (so it formats them as integers) plus the rest of the name (`_name.txt`).  The range is given by the output of `printf … | awk …`.  The `printf()` command lists file names that start with a digit and end with `_name.txt` one per line.  The `awk` command keeps a track of the current maximum number; it coerces the name into a number (`awk` ignores the material after the last digit) and checks whether the number is larger than before.  At the end, it prints two values, the largest value plus 1 and the largest value plus 10 (defaulting to 1 and 10 if there were no files).  Adding the `-w` option to `seq` is irrelevant when you specify `-f` and a format; the file names won't be generated with leading zeros.  There are ways to deal with this if they're crucial — probably simplest is to drop the `-f` option to `seq` and add the `-w` option, and output the output through `sed 's/$/_name.txt/'`.

You can squish the `awk` script onto a single line; you can squish the whole command onto a single line.  However, it is arguably easier to see the organization of the command when they are spread over multiple lines.

Note that (apart from a possible TOCTOU — Time of Check, Time of Use — issue), there is no need to check whether the files exist.  They don't; they'd have been listed by the glob `[0-9]*_name.txt` if they did, and the number would have been accounted for.  If you want to ensure no damage to existing files, you'd need to use `set -C` or `set -o noclobber` and then create the files one by one using shell I/O redirection.

*[…time passes…]*

Actually, you can have `awk` do the file name generation instead of using `seq` at all:

```
touch $(printf '%s\n' [0-9]*_name.txt |
        awk 'BEGIN { max = 0 }
                   { val = $0 + 0; if (val > max) max = val; } 
               END { for (i = max + 1; i <= max + 10; i++)
                         printf "%d_name.txt\n", i
                   }'
       )
```

And, if you try a bit harder, you can get rid of the `printf` command too:

```
touch $(awk 'BEGIN { max = 0 
                     for (i = 1; i <= ARGC; i++)
                     {
                         val = ARGV[i] + 0;
                         if (val > max)
                             max = val
                     }
                     for (i = max + 1; i <= max + 10; i++)
                         printf "%d_name.txt\n", i
                   }' [0-9]*_name.txt
       )
```

Don't forget the `shopt -s nullglob` — that's still needed for maximum resiliency.

You might even choose to get rid of the separate `touch` command by having `awk` write to the files:

```
awk 'BEGIN { max = 0 
             for (i = 0; i < ARGC; i++)
             {
                 val = ARGV[i] + 0;
                 if (val > max)
                     max = val
             }
             for (i = max + 1; i <= max + 10; i++)
             {
                 name = sprintf("%d_name.txt", i)
                 printf "" > name
             }
             exit
           }' [0-9]*_name.txt
```

Note the use of `exit`.  Note that the POSIX specification for [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says that `ARGC` is the number of arguments in `ARGV` and that the elements in `ARGV` are indexed from `0` to `ARGC - 1` — as in C programs.

There are few shell scripts that cannot be improved.  The first version shown runs 4 commands; the last runs just one.  That difference could be quite significant if there were many files to be processed.

Beware: eventually, the argument list generated by the glob will get too big; then you have to do more work.  You might be obliged to filter the output from `ls` (with its attendant risks and dangers) and feed the output (the list of file names) into the `awk` script and process the lines of input once more.  While your lists remain a few thousand files long, it probably won't be a problem.